# Retrieving Records in Dynamics CRM after Logging in using AJAX jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I can successfully reach XRMServices on `ORGANIZATION_URL/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet?$select=AccountNumber` and retrieve customer account number on a browser after logging in. However, there is an authentication service blocking this if I use AJAX. My code is as below

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            url: ORGANIZATION_URL+ "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet?$select=AccountNumber,Telephone1,Telephone2,new_CustomerDiscGroup,EMailAddress1,EMailAddress2,EMailAddress3",
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
            },
            complete: function (XmlHttpRequest) {
                console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });
```

What am I missing???

Comment: Is your AJAX call running within Dynamics CRM e.g. on an entity form? What error message do you receive?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a huge pain, here is the answer to logging in to Dynamics CRM using jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'https://<Your Authentication URL for CRM>/adfs/ls',
    data : {
        UserName : '<username>',
        Password : '<password>',
        wa : 'wsignin1.0',
        wauth : 'urn:federation:authentication:windows',
        wtrealm : '<CRM Location>',
        wct : 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ'
    },
    headers : {
        Accept: 'image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap,application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*','Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    beforeSend : function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr);
    },
    complete : function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr);
    },
    success : function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr);
    },
    error : function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

Hope that helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are doing cross-site scripting error. So you are opening your CRM using for example http://localhost or http://ip_number, and then in your ajax call you are using ORGANIZATION_URL which is probably different (for example http://contosocrm). Make sure that you are calling your ajax request with exactly the same address as you use to access CRM (or the page that is calling ajax)