# Retrieve Dynamics CRM customer information using ODATA and jQuery

Tags: jquery, odata, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to retrieve customer information from Dynamics CRM using jQuery AJAX and ODATA.

```
$.ajax({
    url : oDataUri,
    headers : {
        Accept: 'image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap,application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true,
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    beforeSend : function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr);
    },
    complete : function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr);
    },
    success : function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr);
    },
    error : function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? The error I get is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: Are you accessing CRM data from outside. Can you show the oDataUri value?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the response type is not a JSON string, are you sure that it's JSON, if not you have to remove this :

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: If I remove this, the **authentication fails** i.e I don't get the pop up window where I enter my Username and Password

Comment: don't you fixed this here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43212475/retrieving-records-in-crm-dynamics-after-logging-in-using-ajax-jquery/43809976#43809976

Comment: Sorry. I meant to edit the title of the previous question to remove retrieval. It should have read like _**"Logging into CRM dynamics using jQuery"**_

Comment: so, you are requesting a JSON response but the server side function is sending other type this is why you got that error, also are you sure it's jsonp and not json? if so, can you provide the kind of the server response?

Comment: The first request is supposed to login me in. It is failing (but only on the response type) but still let me in / through. The second request ought to send back ODATA information which it is not.

Comment: I'm trying to run the above code outside Dynamics CRM. However in CRM it works. How do I do this?